# Sorting a DataRow Collection with a value closest to certain value

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, datatable, datarow

I have a `DataRow[]` consisting of 3 columns I want to sort the collection based on a columns value closest to some given value. i.e. `Abs(column - given_value)`.
Can somebody please give me some idea how I can accomplish that ?

Comment: row.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.column - given_value))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var results = collection.OrderBy( 
     row => Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(row["ColumnName"]) - given_value));
```

Or Convert.ToDouble, i don't know the type you are using.

Note: Is the column allows *null*, you should check it for `DBNULL` first before Converting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq and [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> orderedRows = rows
    .OrderBy(r => Math.Abs(r.Field<int>("column") - given_value));
```

If you want to create a new array: `rows = orderedRows.ToArray();`

Replace `r.Field<int>` with the actual type. If it's just a string you need to convert it first:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> orderedRows = rows
    .OrderBy(r => Math.Abs(int.Parse(r.Field<string>("column")) - given_value));
```